How to deploy Shiny App with deprecated maptools
When I try to deploy my shiny app, I get this error:
! All packages must be installed from a reproducible location.✖️ Can't re-install packages installed from source: maptools.

I understand this is because maptools was recently removed from CRAN, so I tried accessing the archive directly:
url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maptools/maptools_1.1-8.tar.gz"
pkgFile <- "maptools_0.2-2.tar.gz"
download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)

install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)

It seems to install successfully, but gives me the same error as if I had no maptools installed: no method or default for coercing "SpatialPolygons"/"SpatialPoints" to "owin"/"ppp"
Alternatively, it would also work if I could fix the part of my code that requires maptools. I am attempting to convert Spatial objects in ppp and owin objects:
place_sp <- as_Spatial(place)
place_sp <- as(place_sp, "SpatialPoints")
place_ppp <- as(place_sp, "ppp")

sz_sp = as(sz, "SpatialPolygons")
sz_owin = as(sz_sp, "owin")


If you install it from github then {renv} (the package that is used to manage dependencies during deployment) should be able to find it. You can use devtools::install_github("cran/maptools")
